# Coloring an AVL tree into a red-black tree with maximum black nodes

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree, red-black-tree

What is an algorithm to color an AVL tree into a red-black tree using a maximal number of black nodes (or minimal number of red nodes)?

I was given [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236842/convert-avl-trees-to-red-black-tree) for a homework problem (color the nodes of an AVL tree to produce a valid red-black tree), and it gave me a thought: when I tried to write an algorithm for this, I tried to write an algorithm which colored as many of the nodes as possible black (e.g. given a perfect binary search tree, all nodes would be black), while the easiest solution (and the one given in the linked question) seems to give red-black trees with either minimal or near-minimal black depth (e.g. given a perfect binary search tree, layers would alternate between red and black). Coloring the most nodes black seemed to be a much harder problem, and while I have a partial solution written in a Java-like language, it is not correct.

```
// Helper to recursively color both children of a node; calls to
// colorAVLChildren do not on their own contribute to recursion
// depth, only the calls which they themselves make to colorAVL.
void colorAVLChildren(Node root) {
    if (root != nil) {
        colorAVL(root.left);
        colorAVL(root.right);
    }
}

void colorAVL(Node root) {
    if (root == nil) {
        return;
    }

    root.color = BLACK;

    // All nil nodes are already black, so regardless of the results
    // of the conditionals, the same effect will overall be had on the
    // coloring of the tree.
    if (root.left != nil) {
        root.left.color = BLACK;
    }
    if (root.right != nil) {
        root.right.color = BLACK;
    }

    if (root.isBalanced()) {
        colorAVLChildren(root.left);
        colorAVLChildren(root.right);
    } else {
        if (root.tallestChild().tallestChild() == nil) {
            root.tallestChild().color = RED;

            return;
        }

        // At least the taller of the tallest child's two children is
        // too tall for the next level of the recursion (i.e., would
        // be taller than other trees at that level, thus violating
        // its invariants); however, it is of the correct black-depth.
        // Therefore, it must be red so that its children are at the
        // correct black-depth, but must not be passed as an argument
        // to colorAVL.
        root.tallestChild().tallestChild().color = RED;

        // This part is incorrect if root.tallestChild().tallestChild() is not balanced
        colorAVLChildren(root.tallestChild().tallestChild());

        // If this tallest child is balanced, treat both of its
        // children the same; otherwise, don't color the shorter of
        // its children at this level of recursion, instead leaving it
        // to the next level to preserve the one-to-one correspondence
        // between tree height and recursion level.
        if (root.tallestChild().isBalanced()) {
            root.tallestChild().shortestChild().color = RED;
            // This part is incorrect if root.tallestChild().shortestChild() is not balanced
            colorAVLChildren(root.tallestChild().shortestChild());
        } else {
            colorAVL(root.tallestChild().shortestChild());
        }

        // The next level in this recursion is the level of the
        // shorter of the two children (as this is the only level
        // which both children are guaranteed to possess); therefore,
        // this shorter child must be colored at the next level of
        // recursion.
        colorAVL(root.shortestChild());
    }
}
```

Comment: A related problem would be to use RNG to pick a random valid coloring for the tree, which would balance performance on the generated trees of additions and deletions (more black nodes generally favours additions, while more red favours deletions). Perhaps some sort of general theory or general algorithm allowing specifying a coloring scheme would allow solving these sorts of problems more easily, but I couldn't figure out how to phrase that as a question.